# nginx django gunicorn 404 static file not loading

Tags: django, nginx, gunicorn, django-staticfiles

I have been trying to solve this error for almost 13 hours, looking for thousands of stackoverflow questions and questions of other communities but I still can't find the answer.
 What I'm trying to do is solve nginx not serving static files.
 as I said on the top, I tried thousands of answers and none of them seem to work for me.

I post only the scripts in nginx /sites-available/ because I think that is the primary script for this question.

```
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name localhost 127.0.0.1;

        location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
        location /static {
                autoindex on;
                alias /home/ngx/pid/static/;
        }

        location / {
                include proxy_params;
                proxy_pass http://unix:/run/gunicorn.sock;
        }
}
```

I use gunicorn for loading django and also the frontend is made with react so without `main.js` I can't do anything.
`ngx` is not a default user - I made it and also I followed [this DigitalOcean](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-django-with-postgres-nginx-and-gunicorn-on-debian-10) tutorial.(Although I didn't follow all of them - I edited after reading answers by other people.

```
Directory
/home/ngx/pid (django root)
        ㄴ diary (project root - settings.py, wsgi.py etc.)
        ㄴ djenv (virtualenv)
        ㄴ frontend (react)
        ㄴ manage.py
        ㄴ static (made by python3 manage.py collectstatic)
```

Error URL:
`http://example.com/static/css/index.css`
`http://example.com/static/frontend/main.js` <- React JS file

Error Code: `404 Not Found`

Comment: Instead of `alias /home/ngx/pid/static/;` can you try `alias /home/ngx/pid/;` ? Did you run `collectstatic` ?

Comment: location and **alias** must have equal leading/trailing slashes

Comment: doesn't work...

Comment: Try `root /home/ngx/pid;` instead of `alias /home/ngx/pid/static/;`

Comment: I tried that but doesn't work also...

Comment: Is your react output file (main.js) located in static/frontend/ ? As I see you have another frontend folder which isn't in the static folder.

Comment: @E Paul the react output file is in /pid/frontend/static/frontend/main.js and I used `collectstatic` so it is on pid/static/frontend/main.js too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't mention that I am using DDNS and port-forwarding my Linux machine to get access from the outside internet.
 and I am also new to Nginx I didn't know that I had to add the site domain name at `server_name`.
 I added my site domain to `server_name` and now it works properly.
It is similar to `ALLOWED_HOSTS` in Django.
Thanks to everyone who helped me.

The code that worked

```
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name localhost 127.0.0.1 MYSITE_DOMAIN;

        location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
        location /static/ {
                root /home/ngx/pid;
        }

        location / {
                include proxy_params;
                proxy_pass http://unix:/run/gunicorn.sock;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try the following configuration:

```
location /static/ {
                root /home/ngx/pid;
        }
```

`Alias` is for defining a replacement for the specified location, probably the reason it's not working.